# Why locking a control itself and access to it synchronically can cause a deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, deadlock

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Thread t = new Thread(() =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(30);
      lock (lstDownload)
      {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(i.ToString());
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
          lstDownload.Items.Add(lvi);
        });
      }
    }
  });
  t.IsBackground = true;
  t.Start();
}
```

Look, in this case, run this method repeatly and quickly can cause deadlock, which freezes the whole UI.

But if I change to `lock(AnyOtherControl)` No matter how I run the method, it won't cause deadlock.

Can any one explain what happened and tell the difference between this two case. (especially why the deadlock no longer come out locking the different control).

Comment: I assume it's because Invoke() also tries to lock the control? Just use your own lock object, that way you know exactly what it is used for.

Comment: You should be calling lock on an object used specifically for locking, not on a control.